# ¿Por que no se cambia la clase en un html generado con un json?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, estoy usando un json para imprimir el resultado en html, tambien uso un `a` con su estilo, que cambia la clase si está en dark-mode tiene su clase, y si está en modo claro, tiene otra clase, si el html lo pongo directamente en el archivo html si funciona, pero como yo lo traigo desde un archivo js, parece ignorar, y no cambia esta clase, al hacer  esto, el boton en dark-mode, se ve oscuro, cosa que hace confundir al usuario, y viceversa.
Asi tengo la estructura, conformada con un home.html, un dark-mode.js, el App.js, y finalmente el codigop que hace cambiar esta clase.
Este es mi `home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">

         <div id="redes"></div>
         <div id="buton"></div>
         <div id="d"></div>
         <hr>
         <div id="Matchs"></div>
      </div>

      <script src="dark-mode.js"></script>
      <script src="App.js"></script> <!-- Genero el HTML con el JSON -->

      <script type="text/javascript">
//Este es el cript basico para cambiar la clase del boton
         let is_dark=document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("dark-mode");let elements=document.getElementsByClassName("waves-effect");for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){if(!is_dark){elements[i].classList.remove("waves-light");elements[i].classList.remove("btnoutlinelight");elements[i].classList.add("waves-dark");elements[i].classList.add("btnoutlinedark")}else{elements[i].classList.remove("waves-dark");elements[i].classList.add("waves-light");elements[i].classList.remove("btnoutlinedark");elements[i].classList.add("btnoutlinelight")}}
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Lugo tengo el `dark-mode.js`

```
function fuctiondarkmode() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

   if (document.body.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode','true');
   }else{
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode','false');
   }
}

  if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') === 'true') {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById("buton").innerHTML = "<span onclick='fuctiondarkmode(); location.reload();' class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutline' style='background-color: #ffffff00;''><b>Modo oscuro: ON</b></span>  ";
  }else{
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById("buton").innerHTML = "<span onclick='fuctiondarkmode(); location.reload();' class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutline' style='background-color: #ffffff00;''><b>Modo claro: ON</b> ";
  }
```

Y por ultimo, el `App.js`

```
const apiurl='https://apijson.net/test.json'

fetch(apiurl)
.then (response => response.json())
.then (function(data){
    let html='';
    data.forEach(function(data){

       html += `
                    <a class="waves-effect outline ahref waves-dark btnoutlinedark" href="${data.Es.valor1}" style="background-color: #ffffff00;"><b>1</b></a>  
                    <a class="waves-effect outline ahref waves-dark btnoutlinedark" href="${data.Es.valor2}" style="background-color: #ffffff00;"><b>2</b></a>  
                    <a class="waves-effect outline ahref waves-dark btnoutlinedark" href="${data.Es.valor3}" style="background-color: #ffffff00;"><b>3</b></a>  
                `;
    })
    document.getElementById('Matchs').innerHTML=html;


})

.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Pero no hace nada, si el body tiene la clase `dark-mode` deberian cambiar la clase de esos botones, pero no lo hace, ¿como deberia hacer que funcione?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el JSON?

Comment: no lo pase en el codigo, por que?

Answer (score 1):

No te debe tomar los estilos por que estás insertando elementos nuevos después de cargar todo el DOM y ejecutar el `script`.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos esto:

```
<body>
  <button id="btnFirst"></button>
  <span id="Matchs"></span>
  <script>
    darkMode();
  </script>
</body>
```

Al cargar la página, el botón tomará los cambios que haya dentro de la función `darkMode();`, pero el `span` no porque no tiene contenido.

Posteriormente insertamos elementos nuevos al `span` con esta línea:

`document.getElementById('Matchs').innerHTML=html;`

Como el `script` ya se había ejecutado, esos nuevos elementos dentro del `span` no tomarán los cambios.

Lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar de nuevo la función `darkMode();` después de insertar los elementos nuevos al `span`, algo así...

```
<body>
  <button id="btnFirst"></button>
  <span id="Matchs"></span>
  <script>
    darkMode();
  </script>
  <script>
    ...
    document.getElementById('Matchs').innerHTML=html;
    darkMode();
  </script>
</body>
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente.

Si quedan dudas, comenta.

Comment: Yo tengo orden, un boton que llama a la funcion darkmode, luego en el body, el `App.js` que es el que tiene el que genera el HTML, y luego arriba del `</body>` ese script que cambia la clase, no entiendo como deberia ordenarlo

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues la estructura de tu código a la pregunta para que sea mas fácil identificar donde está el problema. De otro modo te estaría dando sugerencias al azar hasta darle al clavo y no es la idea.

Comment: Perfecto, ahi añadi completo la estructura de los archivos, y su orden.

Comment: Intenta transponer el orden de los dos archivos `js`, es decir, que primero se ejecute App.js y luego dark-mode.js. Otra opción es pasar el código que tienes en el último script al archivo dark-mode.js, lo envuelves en una función y la ejecutas con el evento `onload`.

Comment: Poner el `App.js` antes que `dark-mode.js` si funciona, pero solo si recargo refrescando el caché, si no, no cambia

Comment: Ese ya es otro tema... puedes forzar la no lectura de la caché agregando ciertas etiquetas `meta` en el `head`. [Aquí puedes encontrar info al respecto](https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/forzar-leer-el-cache-del-navegador-web/)